# What is the cardinality of a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Well, I have seen some other post related to the cardinality of a $\sigma$-algebra, but they all seem to be related to very specific examples and situations.

My question here, is from somebody who just started learning elementary probability theory and measure theory. No background on real analysis.

I know that a $\sigma$-algebra must satisfy three conditions. Once we prove that they are satisfied we can conclude that.

However, I cannot find information about the cardinality of a $\sigma$-algebra.

I mean, we can have some class of subsets of $\Omega$ and generate the $\sigma$-field. But what can be said about the cardinality of the resulting set??

Hope you guys may provide some insight and intuition behind understanding this topic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what do you want to know?  Different $\sigma$-algebras have different cardinalities...

Comment: A question could be: "is there a countable $\sigma$-algebra?"

Comment: "*but they all seem to be related to very specific examples and situations*" Yes... that sounds about right.  Cardinality of a sigma algebra on $X$ can range from $2$ to $2^{|X|}$ and depend heavily on what the specific example you are working on is.  Even with knowing about the existence of some class of subsets which generate it, the cardinality can vary wildly.  We would need to know specifics about how much and what kind of overlap those subsets have with one another.

Comment: I see, thanks for the replies. So, we can say that cardinality of a $\sigma$-algebra always depend on information that should be provided regarding how the field is generated. I understand that the cardinality starts from 2 since we can have the trivial field $\{  \emptyset,\Omega \}$ then, we can have many other elements included so, $2^{|X|}$. 

So, there is no a direct implication for example, by saying that if we generate a $\sigma$-field from an uncountable class $\mathcal{C}$, the $\sigma$-field will be of uncountable cardinality.

Comment: Well, a $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$ always includes $\mathcal{C}$. So it always has cardinality at least as great as $\mathcal{C}$. In particular if $\mathcal{C}$ is uncountable then so is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}$. ... It can be strictly greater. For example, let $\mathcal{C} = \{ [q,\infty) \subset \mathbb{R} \mid q \in \mathbb{Q} \}$, a countable collection. You can show that $\mathcal{C}$ generates the usual (standard) Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, which is uncountable.